# Which C# SOAP Client Library is easiest to use?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, client-side

I would like to connect to a SOAP web service using C#.  Before I jump right in, trying anything Google throws at me I would like to ask what is the cleanest and best way to do it where most of the work is done for me.

I would like a high level method, where I give it a WSDL and it will basically handle a lot of things for me.  I of course don't want to have to do any of the XML, except to see what it is doing to debug.

What is the nicest fanciest library/method that Microsoft has for doing this?  Notice that I'm more concerned with optimizing developer time over performance, though there probably isn't much difference in this situation.

Here is a better explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish.
[a better OOP approach to multiple SOAP web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56996588/using-a-more-oop-method-instead-of-switch-statements-for-soap-web-service-calls)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What Assaf said. You have the choice between using a Web reference (wrapper around WSDL.exe) and using a Service reference (wrapper around svcutil.exe). Service references are .NET 3.0+ and part of the WCF way of doing things.

Personally I still use Web references most of the time, but YMMV.

Edit: [screenshot of the two menu options](http://andrewtokeley.net/archive/2008/07/10/the-difference-between-ldquoadd-web-referencerdquo-and-ldquoadd-service-referencerdquo.aspx) :)

Comment: The Link is broken

Answer (score 5):

That's what Web References in C# projects do.
When you add a web reference it parses the WSDL and creates strongly typed classes for the API.

Comment: Looks like it's unanimous.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

No need for any fancy library... This is built-in functionality...
Just add a Service Reference to your project right from the context menu in Visual Studio.

Comment: I just posted a question to better understand my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56996588/using-a-more-oop-method-instead-of-switch-statements-for-soap-web-service-calls