# Accessing a web service WSDL file

Tags: web-services, web-applications

I am fairly new to Web Services and had the following doubt.

My understanding is a Web Service uses WSDL to describe its Service Contract i.e the operations it supports, binding and address of web service.

Now, if I want to write a web application that wants to use services from any web service, how do I get its WSDL file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havent specified the language that you are using fot writing your web application, so let me give you a generic answer. You need a **soap client** to negotiate with web service. There are several possible options for soap client. For eg:

1. Python: [SUDS](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation)
2. PHP: [SoapClient Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)
3. Ruby: [SOAP4R](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/soap4r/)
4. C#: [just add service reference (natively available)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963794/which-c-sharp-soap-client-library-is-easiest-to-use)
5. Java: [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) brief [Example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-soapcl/) I found