# The XML request payload that Magento API's call method expects

Tags: c#, magento, xml-rpc

I wrote a generic XML RPC framework in C#. I am now using it to call the Magento API.

I first called the `login` method and got a valid session ID. But I am not sure what the way to call the `call` method is because all examples I have seen so far have been of clients using a SOAP proxy to call it from either Java or PHP.

The syntax of those proxy calls reveals that the method signature must be something like this:

```
proxy.call ( stringSessionId, stringMethodYouWantToCall, 
                           new object[] { param1, param2, ... } );
```

where `call` is the method I am referring to. `stringMethodYouWantToCall` is some PHP side method that the Magento framework's `call` method will call.

Thing is, when I do this, I get all sorts of errors. But I would digress if I talked about those.

**My question really is: could you please provide me with a sample xml-rpc payload that the call method expects. I will build it from there.**

**Aside**
Currently, a Java app calls the Magento API. I could use Fiddler to see the HTTP traffic / request body it sends to Magento, but I do not know how to configure Tomcat to send its traffic to Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure writing your own XML RPC implementation is a good thing, as I am sure there are fully functional C# libraries out there which will solve the issue for you. But if this is some academic or a hobby project, then by all means you should take a look at this generice XML RPC client https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php. And for a specific use case take a look at the __call method here for the SOAP client https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Soap/Client.php

Just to be sure if you are going the right direction check how they have implemented the entire SOAP client would be a good reference.

Also please take a look here might help you? [Which C# SOAP Client Library is easiest to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963794/which-c-sharp-soap-client-library-is-easiest-to-use)