# Using a more OOP method instead of switch statements for SOAP web service calls

Tags: c#, web-services, oop, soap

I'm trying to figure out if there is a better way to accomplish what I have below.
We have multiple(12) SOAP web services all from the same vendor. So all the calls are the same (ex. getclaim(), editclaim(), addclaim(), etc, etc)

ex. of two web service urls

> https://trustonline.delawarecpf.com/tows/webservicefk.svc
>   https://trustonline.delawarecpf.com/tows/webservicepcc.svc

But we have all of the ws calls in separate files (super redundant), one for each web service.
So I'm trying to figure out how to combine them into a single file.

I think can do something like this below, where I have a switch or if statement that determines the web service and the User object from each service, but this seems a little non obj oriented, so I'm looking to see if there is a better way?

Here is what I'm currently doing, but looking for a better way.

```
    // initializing the web services and fetching some data at the end
    public void InitWebService(string webserviceUrl, int webServiceType)
    { 
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(webserviceUrl);

        ChannelFactory channelFactory = null;
        switch(webServiceType)
        {
            case 1:
                channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<WebServiceAWI>(binding, endpoint);
                break;
            case 2:
                channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<WebServiceBG>(binding, endpoint);
                break;
            etc.
        }            

        var webservice = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        var user = null; // CAN'T HAVE NULL HERE
        switch(webServiceType)
        {
            case 1:
                user = WebservicereferenceA.User();
                break;
            case 2:
                user = WebserviceReferenceB.User();
                break;
            etc.
        }

        user.UserName = webservice.EncryptValue("someone");
        user.Password = webservice.EncryptValue("password");

        // get some data
        var result = webservice.AttorneysGet(user);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be using that logic a lot, you may as well put it into another factory and call on that instead.

I'd probably consider changing the `int` up for an `enum`. Something like:

```
public enum ServiceType
{
    A,
    B
}

public class ServiceFactory 
{
    public ChannelFactory CreateChannelFactory(ServiceType type, BasicHttpBinding binding, EndpointAddress endpoint) 
    {
        switch(type) 
        {
            case ServiceType.A: 
                return new ChannelFactory<WebServiceAWI>(binding, endpoint);
            case ServiceType.B:
                return new ChannelFactory<WebServiceBG>(binding, endpoint);
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just used a int as an example I haven't implemented this yet, as I'm looking to see if I want to rewrite it. The biggest problem I have is with setting the User. I can't initially hav a null value there...